# How to drop table using pyspark jdbc connector to teradata?

Tags: pyspark, jdbc, teradata

I can select from the teradata database, but I cannot drop using pyspark.

I have also used jaydebeapi to drop the table in the same spark session and that works.
Was hoping someone may have encountered the same issue.

```
drop_sql = """ (DROP TABLE <DB_NAME>.<TABLENAME>) """


conn = spark.read \
.format("jdbc") \
.option("driver","com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver") \
.option("url","jdbc:teradata://<IP_ADDRESS>/DATABASE=. <DB_NAME>,TMODE=ANSI,CHARSET=UTF8,TYPE=FASTLOAD,LOGMECH=LDAP") \
.option("query", drop_sql) \
.option("user", user) \
.option("password",password)\
.option("fetchsize",10000).load()
```

ERROR:

`Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o265.load. : java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 17.20.00.15] [Error 3707] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error, expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier or an 'UDFCALLNAME' keyword or a 'SELECT' keyword or '(' between '(' and the 'DROP' keyword.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spark.read` provides a higher level language. It's not a Terradata driver for python.

- Queries you pass to `spark.read.format('jdbc').option(query, '...')` can only contain `SELECT` statements.
- Whatever you provide there is in-turn wrapped in an outer `SELECT` by spark code before it's sent to underlying driver for execution. E.g.

```py
spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("query", "SELECT c1, c2 FROM t1") \
    .option("partitionColumn", "partiion_id") \
    .option("lowerBound", "1") \
    .option("upperBound", "300") \
    .option("numPartitions", "3") \
    .load()
```

Would translate to 3 queries like these being executed in parallel on underlying DB. Please note real ones would be slightly different, this is curated for academic purpose:

```sql
SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT c1, c2 FROM t1 WHERE partiion_id BETWEEN 1 AND 100) t
SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT c1, c2 FROM t1 WHERE partiion_id BETWEEN 100 AND 200) t
SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT c1, c2 FROM t1 WHERE partiion_id BETWEEN 100 AND 300) t
```

So in your case Terradata is unhappy because Spark is executing something along the lines of:

`SELECT t.* FROM (DROP TABLE <DB_NAME>.<TABLENAME>) t`

---

What you have is not "pyspark jdbc connector to teradata". It's "Terradata JDBC driver".

To run [Terradata specific SQL](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-Database-SQL-Fundamentals/June-2017/SQL-Data-Definition-Control-and-Manipulation/Data-Definition-Language) on Terradata you need write python code that uses Terradata specific driver. [Here is an example](https://github.com/Teradata/python-driver/blob/master/samples/FastExportTable.py#L7-L16).

```py
import teradatasql

with teradatasql.connect (host="whomooz", user="guest", password="please") as con:
    with con.cursor () as cur:
        try:
            sRequest = "DROP TABLE <DB_NAME>.<TABLENAME>"
            print (sRequest)
            cur.execute (sRequest)
        except Exception as ex:
            print ("Ignoring", str (ex).split ("\n") [0])
```

If you want to run this code on Databricks/Spark-cluster then you'll have to [add the jdbc driver library](https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/index.html) on the cluster in question. E.g. as a [cluster library](https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/cluster-libraries.html#install-a-library-on-a-cluster). And then run the code above on that cluster.

I assume you've already done this given the error you're getting.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  You are indeed correct. I successfully used the jaydebeapi library with the same Teradata jar.  The connection string works and I’m able to drop the table.  I’ll have to try with the teradatasql once I create a new image.